# How do I compress a full directory and save the zip name as the date and time of it being compressed

Tags: php, zip

I found this php script online:

```
$zipFile = "./backup.zip";
$zipArchive = new ZipArchive();

if (!$zipArchive->open($zipFile, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE))
    die("Failed to create archive\n");

$zipArchive->addGlob("./*.txt");
if (!$zipArchive->status == ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OK)
    echo "Failed to write files to zip\n";

$zipArchive->close();
```

I want the compress script to backup the website and not delete any files after backup.

I want the zip to save to **/backups/(Date and time of backup).zip**. How can I do this?

Another feature I need is for the backup to additionally save to dropbox or some other domain. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? SO is not a free coding site. You need to show your research and the things, which you have tried. [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) might help you to improve your question.

Comment: I have shown my research. I am trying to work on a script that automatically backs up each page after each time it gets loaded by a visitor.